# Fotorama: Make slideshow the height of the container, not the window

Tags: fotorama

Using the option `data-height="100%"` sets the height of the Fotorama to the height of the window. This is by design. However I would prefer it set to the height of the parent element.

I'm containing the Fotorama inside of a container which is almost full height, but has padding for navigation which is fixed to the bottom of the window. But on mobile is fixed to the header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
height = $('#fotorama').parent().outerHeight()
$('#fotorama').fotorama({width: '100%', height: height})
```

Comment: Please add a plain-English explanation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer